# how to replace a specific text line within a html page with beautiful soup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm total newbie with `beautiful soup` with `python`.

I'm trying to replace the line below

```
Assurez-vous de bien recevoir tous nos messages en ajoutant tribeca@yes.net a votre carnet d'adresses.
```

With

```
yaya toure
```

I've done this piece of code (see below)

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup   
import re

url = r"/cygdrive/d/ope_mdl/bsoup/test_toto.html"
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

soup.replace('Assurez-vous de bien recevoir tous nos messages en ajoutant tribeca@yes.net a votre carnet d\'adresses.', 'Yaya Toure')
```

As you see, `votre carnet d'adresses.` already has a `'`. I've put a `\`

However, it does not seem to replace the text.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** Line 1 to 5 work fine. You have to create a HTML file in your local drive. Only the line 6 is creating issues for me.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, if you have any tips, they are more than welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to find `BeautifulSoup.replace` in pydoc.  So I believe that you shouldn't be using it in your code.  So instead of that use

```
search_text = 'Assurez-vous de bien recevoir tous nos messages en ajoutant tribeca@yes.net a votre carnet d\'adresses.'
soup.find(text=lambda x: x.startswith(search_text)).replaceWith('Yaya Toure')
```

**Edit**: Note that we have to pass the function as the text argument because your particular html file has your search string separated by more text with a `<br />` in the middle of the text.  This causes the text attribute to be the concatenation of the your intended string and the garbage data.

Comment: Hi @randomusername I ran the last line and I've got this `traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
`

Comment: @AndyK Then the text was not in the html file.  Either the html file was incorrect or the ``search_text`` was incorrect.

Comment: I'm sorry but I've put everything in your solution and I have that issue , @randomusername . I'm running on cygwin and python 2.7

Comment: @AndyK post your html file

Comment: You got it @randomusername?

Comment: Can you explain a bit this part, please? `text=lambda x: x.startswith(search_text))`